# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "inserir", "insertar" e "injerir"? ¿Cuándo son equivalentes?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, definiciones, significado

Tengo cierto cacao con las palabras *insertar* e *inserir*. Como [diría Camilo Sesto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-94K3PrrhWk), ya no puedo más, siempre la misma historia.

En parte la confusión viene de que en catalán la palabra "inserir" quiere decir "insertar". Esa era mi teoría, pero mirando las definiciones del DRAE me doy cuenta de que en ciertas acepciones son sinónimas... pero luego *injiere* la palabra "injerir", a la que yo le daba otro significado:

> **[inserir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LkQEbSH)**
>   Del lat. inserĕre 'introducir'.
>   1. tr. [injerir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ld3rZOs).
>
> **[insertar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LkUR02C)**
>   Del lat. insertāre 'injerir'.
>   1. tr. Incluir, introducir algo en otra cosa. U. t. c. prnl.
>   2. tr. Dar cabida a una información en las columnas de un periódico o de una revista.
>   3. prnl. Biol. Dicho de un órgano: Introducirse más o menos profundamente entre las partes de otro, o adherirse a su superficie.
>
> **[injerir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ld3rZOs)**
>   Del lat. inserĕre.
>   1. tr. Injertar plantas.
>   2. tr. Meter una cosa en otra.
>   3. tr. Introducir en un escrito una palabra, una nota, un texto, etc.
>   4. prnl. Entremeterse, introducirse en una dependencia o negocio.

Así que mi duda es: ¿qué acepción de "injerir" tiene "inserir"? ¿La transitiva en el sentido de injertar plantas? ¿Hay algún caso en el que "injerir" e "insertar" sean intercambiables, como por ejemplo las acepciones insertar.1 con injerir.2?

Comment: Me doy cuenta por cierto de que las etiquetas necesitan cierta limpia: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, definiciones y significado parece algo redundante y con muchas intersecciones.

Comment: Otra pregunta que leo y me provoca un trabalenguas: _El inserizador está injerizado, ¿quién lo desinjerizará? El desinsertador que lo desinserice buen desinjerizador será._

Comment: @CarlosAlejo prometo un bounty a quien lo diga en voz alta y comiendo polvorones.

Comment: ¿Y qué tal Embutir?

    embutir [Conjugar el verbo embutir]

    De embotir.

    1. tr. Hacer embutidos.
    ...
    7. tr. desus. Injerir, mezclar unas cosas con otras.

Comment: _Inserir_ e _injerir_ no las he usado nunca como verbo. Solo conozco las palabras _injerto_ e _injerencia_, pese a que considero que manejo bastante vocabulario. ¿Son comunes en España?

Comment: @Rodrigo _injerir_ se usa en España especialmente en su primera y cuarta acepción, esta última normalmente con el sustantivo: _no me gustan las injerencias de tus padres en la educación de nuestro hijo_. La segunda nunca la usé y la tercera tampoco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿qué acepción de "injerir" tiene "inserir"? ¿La transitiva en el
>   sentido de injertar plantas?

Tal como dice la entrada de [*inserir*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Hz0Qm1huwD6QceSTe6) del DPD:

> **inserir.** ‘Insertar o introducir [una cosa] en otra’.(...) También puede emplearse, con este sentido, la variante injerir (→
>   **injerir(se), 2**).

En la entrada del DPD para [*injerir(se)*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=3qZrr62YyD6c4sUaZB) hay 3 notas, pero la correspondiente a *inserir* es [la segunda](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=3qZrr62YyD6c4sUaZB#2):

> **2.** Como transitivo, significa ‘meter o introducir [una cosa] en otra’: «*Timoneda* [...] *se percató de que las partes jocosas se
>   podían desglosar e injerir EN otras comedias*» (Asensio *Itinerario*
>   [Esp. 1965-71]); con este sentido puede emplearse también la variante
>   *inserir* (→ inserir).

Este significado ("meter o introducir [una cosa] en otra") es la correspondiente a la [entrada 2 del DLE para *injerir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ld3rZOs), que es la [entrada 1 de *insertar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LkUR02C) ("introducir algo en otra cosa").

En resumen:

- Todo *inserir* es *injerir*, pero solo *injerir(2)* es *inserir*, según el DPD. No obstante, el ejemplo que proporciona se refiere a textos y podría ser también *injerir(3)*. La 3ª acepción es un caso particular de la 2ª que tiene entidad propia.
- Yo no usaría *inserir* para las plantas, aunque a veces parte del injerto se introduzca en la planta receptora y tampoco usaría *insertar* por inespecífico.
- Sí podría utilizarse en sentido figurado *injertar* para textos (la 3ª acepción) pero tiene que haber una buena razón estilística para ello.